# $x,y,z\ge 0: x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Find minimum $P=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{y^3+2zx}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{z}{z^3+2xy}}.$

Tags: inequality

Problem. Let $x,y,z\ge 0: x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Find minimum $$P=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{y^3+2zx}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{z}{z^3+2xy}}.$$

After check some special values of $x,y,z$, I think Min $P=\sqrt[3]{16}$ achieved at $(x,y,z)=\left(0,\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right).$

I tried the following Holder (by a hint of Micheal Rozenberg): $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}\right)^3\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^4}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^4}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2xy-x\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}\right)\right)^4}{\sum\limits_{cyc}x^3(x^3+2yz)\left(y-\sqrt{\frac{yz}{2}}+z\right)^4}}\geq\sqrt[3]{16},$$
where the last inequality helps to get a polynomial inequality. I checked and it seems true.

To end proof, we can used BW to verified but it is very ugly. I hope to see a simple idea. Thank you.

Comment: So, forget my comment !

Comment: Yes, now we need to prove my guess.

Comment: Acording to many analogue results, in principle, it should be equal to the value of the function when the three variables are equal, which would give as a minimum (Don't trust my calculations)
$$\dfrac{3\sqrt[3]3}{\sqrt[3]9+6}\approx 0.53548314$$

Comment: A similar problem that may be useful : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h368787p2030510

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Lagrange multiplier.
Let $L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{y^3+2xz}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{z}{z^3+2xy}}-\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1).$ 
Now let's derive: 
$L^{'}(x,y,z,\lambda)_x=0=\frac{-2x^3+2yz}{3x^\frac{2}{3}(x^3+2yz)^\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{2zy^\frac{1}{3}}{3(y^2+2xz)^\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{2yz^\frac{1}{3}}{3(z^2+2xy)^\frac{4}{3}}-2\lambda x\\
L^{'}(x,y,z,\lambda)_y=0=-\frac{2zx^\frac{1}{3}}{3(x^3+2yz)^\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{-2y^3+2xz}{3y^\frac{2}{3}(y^3+2xz)^\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{2xz^\frac{1}{3}}{3(z^3+2xy)^\frac{4}{3}}-2\lambda y\\
L^{'}(x,y,z,\lambda)_z=0=-\frac{2yx^\frac{1}{3}}{3(x^3+2yz)^\frac{4}{3}}-\frac{2xy^\frac{1}{3}}{3(y^3+2xz)^\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{-2z^3+2xy}{3z^\frac{2}{3}(z^3+2xy)^\frac{4}{3}}-2\lambda z\\
L^{'}(x,y,z,\lambda)_\lambda=0=0-(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$

From here you need to solve 4 equaitons with 4 different variables.
Couldn't post it as a comment because it was too long. Good luck.

Comment: DO you say it's not hard to solve the 4 equations!? It's very hard!

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts.**

It suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$,
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}\cdot \frac{1}{2}} \ge 2.$$

**Fact 1.** Let $a, b, c \ge 0$ with $a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3 + 24a^3b^3c^3 \ge 1$. Then $a + b + c \ge 2$.
(The proof is given at the end.)

Let
$$a := \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{x^3+2yz}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}, \quad b := \sqrt[3]{\frac{y}{y^3+2zx}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}, \quad c := \sqrt[3]{\frac{z}{z^3+2xy}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}.$$

We have
$$a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3 + 24a^3b^3c^3 \ge 1. \tag{1}$$
*Note*: (1) is verified by *Mathematica*.

By Fact 1, we have $a + b + c \ge 2$.

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 1.*

Equivalently, we need to prove that, for all $a, b, c\ge 0$ with $a + b + c < 2$,
$$a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3 + 24a^3b^3c^3 < 1. \tag{A1}$$

If $a + b = b + c = c + a = 1$ (that is $a = b = c = 1/2$),
clearly (A1) is true. In the following, WLOG, assume that $a + b \ne 1$.It suffices to prove that, for all $a, b \ge 0$ with $1 \ne a + b < 2$,
$$a^3b^3 + b^3(2 - a - b)^3 + (2 - a - b)^3a^3 + 24a^3b^3(2 - a - b)^3 < 1. \tag{A2}$$

Let $p = a + b$ and $q = ab$. We have $0\le p < 2$ and $p \ne 1$ and $p^2 \ge 4q$.

Using $a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2) = p(p^2 - 3q)$, (A2) is written as
$$q^3 + p(p^2 - 3q)\cdot (2 - p)^3 + 24q^3(2 - p)^3 < 1, $$
or
\begin{align*}
 f(q) &:= \left( 24\,{p}^{3}-144\,{p}^{2}+288\,p-193 \right) {q}^{3} \\
 &\qquad + \left( -3
 \,{p}^{4}+18\,{p}^{3}-36\,{p}^{2}+24\,p \right) q+{p}^{6}-6\,{p}^{5}+
 12\,{p}^{4}-8\,{p}^{3}+1\\
 &\ge 0. 
\end{align*}

Note that $f''(q) = 24\,{p}^{3}-144\,{p}^{2}+288\,p-193
= -1 - 24(2 - p)^3 < 0$. Thus, $f(q)$ is concave. Also,
$$f(0) =  \left( {p}^{4}-4\,{p}^{3}+3\,{p}^{2}+2\,p+1 \right)  \left( p-1
\right) ^{2}
 > 0, $$
and
\begin{align*}
 &f(p^2/4) \\
 ={}& \frac{p-2}{64}\cdot ( 24{p}^{8}-96{p}^{7}+96{p}^{6}+15{p
 }^{5}-66{p}^{4}+60{p}^{3}-8{p}^{2}-16p-32)\\
 >{}& 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f(q) > 0$ on $[0, p^2/4]$. We are done.