# If $a+b+c+abc=4,$ prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}\ge \frac{5}{4}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca>0$ and $a+b+c+abc=4.$ Prove that$$\color{black}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}\ge \frac{5}{4}. }$$

---

*Remark.*

My teacher asasigned this problem to our class as a homework. I post it here to look for help and share some thoughts.

Any ideas and comments are welcome. Please feel free to discuss about this inequality.

Here is my attempts.

Since equality holds at $a=b=2;c=0$ we can't use normal approach.

For example, by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality$$\color{black}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}\ge \frac{9}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}+\sqrt{b^2+4ba}+\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}. }$$
But $$\frac{9}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}+\sqrt{b^2+4ba}+\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}- \frac{5}{4}=-\frac{1}{8}$$is already wrong when $a=b=2;c=0.$

---

I'll post more ideas which are not good enough. Now, I hope you consider carefully before voting to close my topic.

I try to use [Jichen lemma](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h194103) which seems not good enough.

Indeed, we can rewrite the original inequality as
$$\color{black}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{16}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}. }$$
I checked that $$\frac{1}{a^2+4bc}+\frac{1}{b^2+4ca}+\frac{1}{c^2+4ab}\ge \frac{9}{16}$$ is not true when $a=b=0.5;c=2.4$.

Also, in comment section, Michael Rozenberg said that the Holder using with $(3a+b+c)^3$ is not good. I hope you can optimize your idea soon.

I'll update more approach when I found it. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can someone, which want to close this topic ,explain us, why did you do it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It seems that the problems is ugly and people didn't like them.

Comment: I don't agree. Your problem is very nice.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement.

Comment: Holder with $(3a+b+c)^3$, which saves the case of the equality occurring, leads to a wrong inequality. Really nice problem!

Comment: Thank you. Maybe another Holder using works.

Comment: @TATAbox I hope RiverLi will share some unique ideas.

Comment: It's really not your fault (or that of your problem). I'm afraid Math.SE has seen an increase in drive-by down-voters and close-voters recently. I suppose they think it's a sign of greater discrimination, when really it's just conceit. If a (non-PSQ) problem is deficient enough for down-votes and close-votes, it's deficient enough for a comment as to why. But go talk to a brick wall.

Comment: Not only that, but some of them have shockingly poor taste. I've seen close-votes and down-votes the last few days on really interesting questions, with a reasonable attempt at solving them shown in the post.

Comment: Really sad to see the toxicity of of this community. Hope this situation improves. @BrianTung you might want to consider making a post on MathSE Meta to discuss the problem.

Comment: @BrianTung I agree with you. Nice point!

Comment: @IraeVid: I've mentioned it on Meta, not with its own post, but in the comment thread of a related question. I don't remember what it was, though. I'd prefer to come up with an initial stab at a mitigation strategy before posting it as its own question.

Answer (score 5):

**Some thoughts.**

By Holder inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + 4bc}} \right)^2\cdot \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^2 + 4bc)(4b + 4c - bc + 4ab + 4ac)^3 \\
 \ge{}& \left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4b + 4c - bc + 4ab + 4ac)\right)^3. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (4b + 4c - bc + 4ab + 4ac)\right)^3 \\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \left(\frac54\right)^2 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a^2 + 4bc)(4b + 4c - bc + 4ab + 4ac)^3. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

(2) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Very nice Holder using! +1

Comment: @TATAbox My two proofs are complicated. According to OP's statement "My teacher asasigned this problem to our class as a homework." There should be a simple solution.

Comment: @RiverLi Do you have pqr solution?

Comment: @Dragonboy I can not find a simple proof in my two answers (complicated proofs are not what I want). I give up currently. Hope to see better solutions.

Answer (score 4):

#### Disclaimer: Not a full solution

##### If one of $a, b, c=0$:

WLOG let $a=0$. Since $ab+bc+ca>0$ we know that $b, c\neq0$.

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+4ca}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+4ba}}\ge \frac{5}{4} \\
\iff &\frac{1}{\sqrt{4bc}}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\geq\frac{5}{4} \\
\iff &\frac{2\sqrt{bc}+4b+4c}{4bc}\geq\frac{5}{4} \\
\iff &8\sqrt{bc}+16b+16c\geq20bc \\
\iff &8\sqrt{bc}+64\geq20bc &\tag{1}\\
\iff &8x+64\geq20x^2 \tag{2}\\
\iff &20x^2-8x-64\leq0
\end{align}$$

$(1)$: The condition $a+b+c+abc=4$ becomes $b+c=4$.

$(2)$: Here $x=\sqrt{bc}$.

However by AM-GM, $0\leq x\leq\dfrac{b+c}{2}=2$. Since $2$ is the bigger root of $20x^2-8x-64$, we know that $20x^2-8x-64\leq0$ is true. Hence, the statement is proved.

#### If $a, b, c\neq0$:

$$\begin{align}
&\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}\geq\frac{5}{4} \\
\iff &\sum\frac{\sqrt{a^2+4bc}}{a^2+4bc}\geq\frac{5}{4} \\
\iff &4\sum\sqrt{a^2+4bc}(b^2+4ca)(c^2+4ab)\geq5(a^2+4bc)(b^2+4ca)(c^2+4ab)
\end{align}$$

Let $x=a^2+4bc$, $y=b^2+4ca$, $z=c^2+4ab$.

$$\begin{align}
\iff &4\sum xy^2z^2\geq 5x^2y^2z^2 \\
\iff &4xy+4yz+4zx\geq 5xyz
\end{align}$$

I need to go now, but I will continue from here if I have the time. I have a feeling that the final step is Schur's Inequality and maybe some of you can try that. Anyone who manages to solve the question from my works, please give me credit.

Answer (score 3):

**Some thoughts.**

By AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2}{\frac{a^2 + 4bc}{2 + bc/2} + (2 + bc/2)} + \frac{2}{\frac{b^2 + 4ca}{2 + ca/2} + (2 + ca/2)} + \frac{2}{\frac{c^2 + 4ab}{2 + ab/2} + (2 + ab/2)} \ge \frac54. \tag{1}$$

(1) is true which is verified by *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark 1*: This is my third proof (the idea) which is better than my two old proofs.

*Remark 2*: Some years ago, I used a similar idea for the problem:
Let $a, b, c > 0$ with $a + b + c = 3$. Prove that
$\left(\frac{a+1}{a+b} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{b+1}{b+c} \right)^{\frac25}+\left(\frac{c+1}{c+a} \right)^{\frac25} \ge 3$.
I gave equivalently the following fact (then let $x = \sqrt[5]{\frac{a+1}{a+b}}$ etc.):

**Fact 1**: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ such that $x^5y^5z^5 \ge \frac{25}{27}$
and $3x^5y^5z^5 - 2(x^5y^5 + y^5z^5 + z^5x^5) + 2(x^5 + y^5 + z^5) = 3$. Then $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 3$.

I also used a similar trick in [P1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456300/prove-that-sum-limits-mathrmcyc-left-a-frac1b-1-right-left-b/3358261#3358261).

*Remark 3*: I think that the spirit of this trick is similar to the pqr method.

- In the pqr method, we use the substitution $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.
  The desired inequality is written in terms of $p, q, r$, say $f(p, q, r) \ge 0$.
  Then we seek some relations among $p, q, r$ which can implies $f(p, q, r) \ge 0$. The relation among $p, q, r$ are $p^2 \ge 3q, p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$, $q^2 \ge 3pr$ etc.
- In this trick, we use $x, y, z$ to substitute the radicals, and the desired inequality is written in terms of $x, y, z$, say$f(x, y, z)\ge 0$.
  Then we seek some relations among $x^2, y^2, z^2$ which can implies $f(x, y, z) \ge 0$. The relations among $x^2, y^2, z^2$ clearly contain no radicals, sometimes it is easy to handle.

*Remark 4*: I used this trick recently in
[P2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782823/if-abbcca-1-prove-frac-sqrta1abc-frac-sqrtb1bca-frac-s/4786697#4786697), [P3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745299/if-a-b-c-ge0abc-3-prove-sqrtabb2-sqrtbcc2-sqrtcaa2-ge-3/4754933#4754933), [P4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735498/abcabc-4-and-prove-sum-cyc-sqrt-fracab9ab9c-ge-3/4795205#4795205), [P5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720881/x-y-z-ge-0-x2y2z2-1-find-minimum-p-sqrt3-fracxx32yz-sqrt3/4796071#4796071).

---

**Some thoughts.**

**Fact 1**: Let $x, y, z > 0$ with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 24$ and $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) - 24x^2y^2z^2 + 2688 \ge 0$. Then $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \ge \frac54$.
(It is verified by *Mathematica*. I think the pqr method works. )

Now, let
$$x = \sqrt{a^2 + 4bc}, \quad y = \sqrt{b^2 + 4ca}, \quad z = \sqrt{c^2 + 4ab}.$$

We can prove that
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 4ab + 4bc + 4ca \le 24, \tag{1}$$
and
$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) - 24x^2y^2z^2 + 2688 \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
(1) and (2) are both true which are verified by *Mathematica*. The proof of (1) is easy. I think the pqr method works for (2): Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.
(2) is written as
$$4\,{p}^{4}q-374\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+1460\,pqr-110\,{q}^{3}-3000\,
{r}^{2}+2688
\ge 0.$$

By Fact 1, we have $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \ge \frac54$.

Comment: Very useful answer! Thank you again +1.

Comment: @Dragonboy You are welcome.

Comment: @RiverLi Could you please tell me how did you come up with the fact 1?

Comment: @Anonymous I have no systematic approach. I do it with try and error.

Comment: @RiverLi Bravo for your nice try.

Comment: I'll track your update. Hope to see more nice ideas.

Comment: @Anonymous I think the author should have a nice proof.

Comment: I try this trick for: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4822134/looking-for-a-tricky-proof-for-two-equality-occuring-abbcca-3 but  I still solved it.

Comment: @Dragonboy Let me try.